# API redirect with ProxyPassMatch

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, opentsdb

I'm trying to redirect [OpenTSDB API](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/put.html) with `apache2`. Here is my configuration([Apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch))

```
ProxyPassMatch /api/* http://127.0.0.1:4343/api/$1
```

The server has `apache2` and `TSDB`. I'm able to access `<ip>:4343/api/version` which is showing version info.

But If I try to access `<ip>/api/version`, showing `Error Code:404 "Endpoint not found"`. So, what's happening here?

Comment: **ProxyPass /api  http://localhost:4343/api**  And the reverse **ProxyPassReverse  /api  http://mySite.myDomain.com/api**

Comment: @JoaoVitorino Thanks for the comment, I want to use `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`, because, in my actual requirement, I don't use same URL forever, it may keep changing  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the regular expression; the apache is forwarding the incorrect API URL to TSDB.

After playing with that apache config, I'm able to redirect the request with below config.

```
ProxyPassMatch "/api/*" "http://127.0.0.1:4343"
```